# Clear Jquery mobile cache

Tags: jquery-mobile, caching

In my game app I use :

```
<div id="player_screen_page" data-role="page" data-dom-cache="true" class="background">...</div>
```

construction to keep previously-visited page. But after use cache I need to delete it. I didn't find answer how to do this on the Internet.